# stackoverflow error when app come from background to foreground

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Sometimes, when my app comes from background to foreground app crashes, whose logcat is as follows,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
       at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
       at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.read(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:74)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:49)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:40)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.getBuffer(ASN1InputStream.java:384)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.createPrimitiveDERObject(ASN1InputStream.java:447)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:184)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:193)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(ASN1InputStream.java:204)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:173)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:272)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.getObject(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:339)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.getExtensionValue(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:325)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertD(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1268)
       at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:310)
       at com.sec.android.security.pkix.SecCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(SecCertPathValidatorSpi.java:100)
       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:190)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:295)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:612)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(NativeCrypto.java)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
       at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:195)
       at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:148)
       at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am using retrofit 2 along with Jackson and this crash occurs on Samsung.

My code for the fragment is as follows,

```
package cl.tp.ui.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cl.tp.ui.iBAPView.Empty_EndlessRecyclerView;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class EngagementsOffers extends 
Fragment implements     ProcessedResult
{
int skip = 0;
private Context context;
private Engagment_offers engagementAdapter;
private List<MJob> engagementJob;

//This is my custom Recyclerview which detects onScroll when end to bottom of page or crossed the threshold.
private Empty_EndlessRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private String accessToken = null;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context=context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_empty_view, container, false);

    initialize(view);
    return view;
}

private void initialize(View view)
{
    accessToken = GeneralFunctions.getStorageManager(context).getValue(Constants.Other.SHAREPREFECE_APPTOKEN.toString(), null);
    mRecyclerView = (Empty_EndlessRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.common_recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    View emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.ev_emptyView);
    TextView textView = (TextView) emptyView.findViewById(R.id.ev_text);

    MUdetails.Data profileDetail=((ApplicationClass)context.getApplicationContext()).getProfileDetail();
    if(profileDetail!=null)
        if(profileDetail.getIsLookingForJob())
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.recycler_empty_engagementoffers));
        else
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.recycler_empty_engagementoffers_off));

    mRecyclerView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    mRecyclerView.setProgressView(R.layout.progress_footer);

    engagementJob = new ArrayList<>();
    engagementAdapter = new Engagment_offers(engagementJob,this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(engagementAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setPager(this);

    mRecyclerView.setRefreshing(true);
    processedResult(null, Constants.Other.LOAD_MORE_METHOD);
}

private void getAllCurrentJobs() {
   /* if (totalSize == skip) {
        mRecyclerView.setRefreshing(false);
        GeneralFunctions.showToast(context.getResources().getString(R.string.toast_no_more_item), context);
        return;
    }*/
    // LogUtil.e("ss:-",mRecyclerView.isRefreshing()+"");
    RetrofitAdapters.createRetrofitService(Api.class).getMyjobOffers(accessToken,10,skip).enqueue(new Callback<MEngagementOffers>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MEngagementOffers> call, Response<MEngagementOffers> response) {
            mRecyclerView.setRefreshing(false);
            GeneralFunctions.parseResponse( response,Constants.CallbackConstants.JOBOFFERS,EngagementsOffers.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MEngagementOffers> call, Throwable t) {
            GeneralFunctions.parserRetrofitError(context, t);
            mRecyclerView.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}


//Custom callback for result parse from retrofit 2
@Override
public <IResponse, IMethod> void processedResult(IResponse iResponse, IMethod iMethod) {
    switch (iMethod.toString()) {
        case Constants.Other.LOAD_MORE_METHOD:
            getAllCurrentJobs();
            break;
        case Constants.CallbackConstants.JOBOFFERS:
        {
            MEngagementOffers mEngagements=((Response<MEngagementOffers>)iResponse).body();
            int size = mEngagements.getData().getNewJobOffers().size();
            skip += size;
            if (size > 0) {
                int prevousSize = engagementJob.size();
                engagementJob.addAll(mEngagements.getData().getNewJobOffers());
                engagementAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(prevousSize, size);
            }
        }break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: may be you are using **too much nested views**

Comment: but that is a simple fragment with recyclerview.

Comment: check your code for multiple threads execution doing the same task, also make sure to close any timer tasks before sending the application to the background in onPause for example.

Comment: try checking for any recursive call that is taking too much heap, try modifying the recursive call, if any

Comment: there is no recursive call, but there is an event like when it reaches a threshold values, api hit is done.

Comment: you will have to include at least some of your code, the stack-trace is not enough.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: @ChrisStewart, no as i don't have any idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something very similar recently.  It turned out I was continuing to add interceptors when I thought adding one would overwrite the original.  Eventually I would get a StackOverflowError much like the stack trace you posted above.  The following discussion helped me figure out what was going on: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2300